# How to change ng-tags-input separator? (default: dash)

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

When adding a space-separated tag, ng-tags-input will replace the space with a dash. How can I keep the space character instead?

Answer (score 8):

I've just found the corresponding directive property on the documentation.
Answer: use `replace-spaces-with-dashes=false`

Comment: That option's default value used to make sense back when ngTagsInput was all about *tags*.  These days that's no longer the case, IMO. I've been thinking of changing that for some time and I guess I will do it for the next release.

Answer (score 3):

In order to replace spaces with underscores, I did the following:

HTML:

```
<tags-input ng-model="model" replace-spaces-with-dashes="false" on-tag-adding="addingTag($tag)"></tags-input>
```

JS:

```
$scope.addingTag = function(tag) {
  tag.text = tag.text.replace(/ /g, '_');
  return tag;
};
```